# Authentication and publih-subscription with nodejs mosca

Tags: node.js, mqtt, iot, mosca

I am creating a iot service with mosca on node js. It crashes constantly to the subscription area and I cannot show the incoming message.

1. How do I prevent it from crashing.
2. How can I see the incoming message?

How can I see the incoming message in the authorizeSubscribe field?
Also authorizeSubscribe field crashes

```
 const mosca = require('mosca');

 const settings = {
     port: 1883,
 };

 const server = new mosca.Server(settings);
 server.on('ready', setup);

 function setup() {
     server.authenticate = authenticate;
     server.authorizePublish = authorizePublish;
     server.authorizeSubscribe = authorizeSubscribe;

     console.log('Mosca server is up and running');
 }

 const authenticate = function(client, username, password, callback) {
     console.log("authenticatealanı", username + " " + password);

     const authorized = (username === 'alice' && password.toString() === 'secret');
     if (authorized) client.user = username;
     callback(null, authorized);
 };


 // In this case the client authorized as alice can publish to /users/alice taking
 // the username from the topic and verifing it is the same of the authorized user
 const authorizePublish = function(client, topic, payload, callback) {
     console.log("authorizePublish " + topic + " "+ payload);

     //callback(null, client.user === topic.split('/')[1]);
 };



 // In this case the client authorized as alice can subscribe to /users/alice taking
 // the username from the topic and verifing it is the same of the authorized user
 const authorizeSubscribe = function(client, topic, message, callback) {
     console.log("new Data Auth subscribe"+ topic );

     console.log(message);

     //callback(null, client.user === topic.split('/')[1]);
 };
```

Comment: "it crashes" isn't helpful, edit the question to include the errors/stacktraces when it fails so we can see why.

Comment: does not give an error. I can't subscribe. so I can't read a published value with subscribe

Comment: Let me explain as follows.

A value has been sent to topic1 / AAA.
There is a subscription to topic1 / AAA.

I subscribed to topic1 / AAA with mqtt.fx. But the values are not coming

Comment: So what you are saying is, it doesn't crash.

Comment: Yes it does not crash, but verified users get no response when subscribed under any topic

Answer (score 0):

If your authorize functions never call the passed in `callback` they will never authorize anything...